# vhdl program not swapping integers

Tags: vhdl, hdl, ghdl

The VHDL code below is a simple swap program. But it is not swapping the inputs `a` and `b`. I have given the transcript values in the comments.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity vhdl_swap is
  port(a,b: inout integer);
end vhdl_swap;

architecture ar of vhdl_swap is
  signal s : std_logic;
begin

  process(s)
    variable var : integer:=0;
  begin
    report "var is" & integer'image(var); -- 0
    report "a is " & integer'image(a);    -- 10 - (given value when simulated)
    report "b is " & integer'image(b);  -- 20 - (given value when simulated)

    report "---------------------------";

    var := a;
    report "var is " & integer'image(var);--var = 10 (assigned properly)
    a<=b;
    report "a is " & integer'image(a);-- a=10(same value but not assigned)
    b<=var;
    report "b is " & integer'image(b);-- b=20(same value but not assigned)

    report "-----------------------------------";

    report "a is " & integer'image(a);--a=10
    report "b is " & integer'image(b);--b=20

    --print()  

  end process;
end;
```

There is something which acts in the statement `a<=b`, but i don't know what prevents itself from assigning it.

Answer (score 3):

The new value assigned with VHDL `<=` is not available for read until an [delta delay](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vhdl+delta+delay) has passed.

This is a fundamental property of VHDL, since it reflects the way register update works then the signal that triggers the update is a clock.

This also means that you can actually do the swap without a variable, but simply doing:

```
a <= b;
b <= a;
```

There are other issues with the code, e.g. what is the `s` used for, using a and b for both input and output will give a drive conflict, unless resolution function is added.

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a new value to a signal in VHDL with `<=` without giving an explicit delay (with `after <time>`), then the new signal value will be available in the next delta cycle. A new delta cycle starts, when the simulator has suspended all processes which have been scheduled for the current delta cycle. And a process is suspended at a `wait` statement. Your process has an implicit `wait on S;` statement at the end, because you described a process with a sensitivity list containing `S`.
You assigned the `inout` ports `a` and `b` here which behave the same as a signal.

Because, the signal update is visible not until the next delta cycle, all your report statements print out the same value for `a` and `b` respectively. That is, they print out the values of `a` and `b` when the process has started / resumed.

Assigning a signal is different to assigning a variable, e.g. `var` in your code, which gets updated immediately.

Your process is executed only once, because the signal `S` is not changed. Every process is executed once after the simulation starts and then suspended at the `wait` statement (the implicit one in your code as described above).

You said, that `a` and `b` have the initial value of 10 and 20, respectively, but I couldn't reproduce this with ModelSim nor GHDL. I tried it with the following testbench which I think is the only possible way:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity vhdl_swap_tb is
end entity vhdl_swap_tb;

architecture sim of vhdl_swap_tb is
  -- component ports
  signal a : integer := 10;
  signal b : integer := 20;
begin  -- architecture sim

  -- component instantiation
  DUT: entity work.vhdl_swap
    port map (
      a => a,
      b => b);

end architecture sim;
```

I had to use initial values for `a` and `b` here, because both ports of mode `inout` and of an unresolved type. Thus, I cannot add a second driver by assigning `a` and `b` in another testbench process.

---

Because, the signal updates are delayed (at least) until the next delta cycle, you do not need an extra variable. Here is a very short example code demonstrating the swapping of two signals:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity swap is
end entity swap;

architecture sim of swap is
  signal a     : integer   := 10;
  signal b     : integer   := 20;
  signal clock : std_logic := '1';
begin

  -- clock generation
  clock <= not clock after 10 ns;

  -- swapping
  process(clock)
  begin
    if rising_edge(clock) then
      a <= b;
      b <= a;
    end if;
  end process;
end sim;
```

The swapping is done at every rising edge of the clock, as can be seen in the following waveform:

[image: simulation output]

Comment: Thank u for ur detailed ans..ur code is cent percent working..i have some questions 1)all ports are signals by default so why ur modifications didnt work in my code when modified.2)i want to swap values given by users during simulation,when i did this in ur program its not swapping,why so?

Comment: @george You need different ports for the inputs and outputs. You can't do swapping with an `inout`. (My code actually demonstrates swapping of register values.)

Comment: so when can we use inout and buffer?

Comment: @george An `inout` can be used for a bidirectional bus, e.g. for communication with an external memory.  A `buffer` is an output which can also be read again within the entity. Both are of no use for swapping.